# Need help understanding CIDR and submask

Tags: networking

I need help with this question: 
You have been assigned the 132.45.0.0/16 network block 
- What is the extended network prefix in CIDR(/n) notation that allows for the creation of 5 subnets? 
- What is the corresponding subnet mask in dotted decimal notation.

I understand that 5 will 2^3 = 8 and that the network prefix for 132.45.0.0 would be 10001000.00101101.00000000.00000000. What I do not understand is since it is /16 do I convert it /24 since subnet mask is 255.255.255.000 = 11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000 and it's extension would have to be the first 3 000 in the last octet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a network : 132.45.0.0/16 with 16 bits

You need 5 subnets which is 3 digits more.

So in total :

- the leftmost 16 bits are the network-id
- the next 3 digits are the subnet-id
- the last 13 digits are the host-id

lets look at the 3rd octet and split it to 3 'subnet bits' for a better view :

```
subnet 0 = 132 . 45 . 000 00000 . 0 -> also 132.45.0.0 /19
subnet 1 = 132 . 45 . 001 00000 . 0 -> also 132.45.32.0 /19
subnet 2 = 132 . 45 . 010 00000 . 0 -> also 132.45.64.0 /19
subnet 3 = 132 . 45 . 011 00000 . 0 -> also 132.45.96.0 /19
subnet 4 = 132 . 45 . 100 00000 . 0 -> also 132.45.128.0 /19
subnet 5 = 132 . 45 . 101 00000 . 0 -> also 132.45.160.0 /19
subnet 6 = 132 . 45 . 110 00000 . 0 -> also 132.45.192.0 /19
subnet 7 = 132 . 45 . 111 00000 . 0 -> also 132.45.224.0 /19
```

Given that, we can say :

- a host 132.45.3.30/16 is in the same network as 132.45.100.40/16
- a host 132.45.3.30/19 is NOT the same subnet as 132.45.100.40/19
- a /16 block can be devided to 8 pieces of /19 blocks
- each piece (subnet) has 13 ramaining bits for available addresses (2^13=8192)
- 8 subnets is the 'most accurate' choice to get 5 subnets ( the division number must be a power-of-2 ( ie. 2,4,8,16,32...etc)

Comment: Hmm okay I think I know what you are talking about so therefore my network prefix would be 19 and my subnet mask would be 255.255.224.0 = 11111111.11111111.11100000.00000000?

Comment: Exactly. writing /19 is the same.as writing 255.255.224.0

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can have 5 subnets of different sizes actually, and size is determined by the subnet mask. So, in this question as I understand, to have 5 subnets you need to add 3 bits to the mask to identify subnet, and you'll have 16 - 5 = 11 bits for the host address inside subnet. And you still can have 3 more subnets really because you used 3 bits for the subnet address.

So it'll be like this 132.45.0.0/19 (You can convert this into decimal notation quite easily I guess :)), for example 10001000.00101101.00100000.00000010 Where 001 is subnet address and 00000.00000010 is host address.

Last time I've seen it was my university networking course, so don't be too harsh on me. See here for details http://blog.pluralsight.com/simplify-routing-how-to-organize-your-network-into-smaller-subnets.